# The best way to save async data with Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, ionic-framework, local-storage

I'm creating a news application by retrieving the data sent by my Json API 
thanks to the Http Client and I would like my data to remain stored if there is no more internet connection or if the user closes / restart the application.

Currently I recover my data in an observable and I loop in asynchronously in my template. If there is no internet connection, I loop my observable to store my data in the native storage of Ionic.

But I suppose there is much simpler and more optimized with perhaps the use of an async / wait, a bit like the AsyncStorage React Native.

What do you advise me? And do you have a sample code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/guides/async-code.html) is the best option for your problems to stored the data locally, with pouchDB you will store the data in a remote database and locally. The local data will be synced to the remote database when an Internet connection is available, and any new data from the remote database will also be synced to the local database if there is new data available.

References : 
https://pouchdb.com/guides/

[Youtube Tutorial for IONIC + pouchDB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWbsN1QIIN8&t=1611s)